# How do i testfor a player using a water bucket with scoreboards?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map and I need a way to test if the player uses a water bucket. I tried `/scoreboard objectives add <Name> stat.useItem362` and `/testfor @a[score_<Name>_min=1]`. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Try stat.useitem.minecraft.water_bucket for the criteria

Answer (score 1):

1.8+ uses name IDs for scoreboard statistics, and in 1.9+ you cannot use numerical IDs.

```
/scoreboard objectives add UseWaterBucket stat.useItem.minecraft.water_bucket

/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar UseWaterBucket
```

Check the sidebar to confirm usage. In 1.8, the statistic will **not** increment when you are in creative mode. You will need to be in survival or adventure mode for that stat to increment. In 1.9+, the stat will increment while in creative mode.

Otherwise, your `/testfor` command is correct:

```
/testfor @a[score_UseWaterBucket_min=1]
```

Answer (score 0):

like the other answer do /scoreboard objectives add useWaterBucket stat.useItem.minecraft.water_bucket
And
with testfor and command blocks u need to use comparators next to the command block to make it work and so on and hope you got help :)